# How to use getframe() with a MATLAB GUIDE (GUI) object to make a movie?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, movie, matlab-guide

I would like to use [getframe](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html) to capture a screenshot of my nice GUI object, which I created using [GUIDE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/guide.html). I can't just use OS PrintScreen functionality because I need to make a movie of something that happens in the GUI window, i.e. capture thousands of frames.

However, since a GUIDE object is apparently not a normal figure (this can be demonstrated by getframe(gcf), which cheerfully opens a new, empty 'Figure 1' window), I'm at a loss what handle I might use to have getframe() capture the contents of my GUI window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: I tried using findobj() to hunt for a handle to my GUIDE object, but no luck. Maybe I'm not using the right thing to search on, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the [`'HandleVisibility` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#HandleVisibility) of your GUIDE GUI figure is set to `'off'`, which would keep its handle from being found by functions like [FINDOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html). However, you can use the function [FINDALL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findall.html) to find the hidden handle of your GUI figure, then pass that handle to [GETFRAME](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html) instead of [`gcf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/gcf.html). For example, if your GUI figure has the title `'My GUI'`, you could do this:

```
hFigure = findall(0,'Name','My GUI');
frameData = getframe(hFigure);
```

Comment: Ah, findall. That does find it. Thanks!